# Are the Drinfeld doubles of twist equivalent Hopf algebras twist equivalent?

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories, braided-tensor-categories

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be finite dimensional Hopf algebras that are twist equivalent, i.e. $H_2$ is obtained from $H_1$ using a [Drinfeld twist](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfel%27d+twist). My question is: are the [Drinfeld double](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfel%27d+double)s $D(H_1)$ and $D(H_2)$ twist equivalent as quasitriangular Hopf algebras? If so, how to explicitly construct the Drinfeld twist relating the two?

My guess is that $D(H_1)$ and $D(H_2)$ are twist equivalent, based on the following reasoning: it is known that two Hopf algebras $H_1,H_2$ are twist equivalent iff their category of representations $Rep(H_1)$ and $Rep(H_2)$ are equivalent as fusion categories. But $Rep(D(H))$ is the [Drinfeld center](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfeld+center) of $Rep(H)$, which is a categorical construction, so  $Rep[D(H_1)]$ and $Rep[D(H_2)]$ should also be equivalent (as braided fusion categories?), implying that $D(H_1)$ and $D(H_2)$ are twist equivalent. Is this correct?